# Calculating bounding box by given center and scale in Android?

Tags: android, scale, resolution

Given these conditions:

- a scale like `1:50000`
- the center of the viewport is `100°E, 20°N`
- the size of the viewport is `400x600`

How can I calculate the bounding box of the viewport?

---

The geographic coordinate system of the map is EPSG:4490.

We want to display them in a different projection like Mercator or [latitude_longitude_projection](http://www.georeference.org/doc/latitude_longitude_projection.htm)(maybe this is the so-said un-projected).

The size of the viewport is in pixels.

Comment: What projection are your map in? Web Mercator? Or do you display a unprojected map in lat/lon? And the size of your viewport, is that in pixels? Is the scale in piels? Do you use any mapping framework/library that might have a function for this?

Comment: What GIS software and version are you using to try and do this?

Comment: @atlefren: I upadte the post.

Comment: @PolyGeo: None, we tried to display the map data in android. And we have not find any library.

Comment: I've just added a tag for android - you may be interested in reviewing other questions related to that platform.

Comment: Android, are you using the Google Maps API or just plain displaying an image? I Would also recommend against using an unprojected coordinate system to display your map, as it will look heavily distorted.

Comment: @atlefren: We use no gis platform. In fact we are just doing what google map did(render the vector data in the client side). The unprojected coordinate system is just one of the projection. We want to support Mercator too.

Comment: Should the android tag on this post be removed?  It doesn't seem to be an Android-specific question, but more general to any web browser.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, with some initial issues cleared out the task is relatively simple.

Scale, prepresented as f.ex 1:50000 means that one unit on the map corresponds to 50.000 units in the real world.

For a paper map printed a scale of 1:50000 this means that 1 meter on the map corresponds to 50.000 meters in the real world, or to make it easier: 1 cm on the map corresponds to 50 meter in the real world. So far, so good.

When computer (or phone screens) enter the show it's much more difficult: the unit of measure on a screen is a pixel, which doesn't map directly to centimeters. OpenLayers are (or at least where) using the "Dots per inch", and assumed that one inch corresponds to 72 pixels (this makes some sense on 72 dpi screens, but is wrong on i.e Retina Displays. But for now, lets stick to 72 dpi (as this is what most mapping libraries does (I think, corrections welcome)).

OpenLayers has a function OpenLayers.Util.getResolutionFromScale (see [source](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/lib/OpenLayers/Util.js)):

```
OpenLayers.Util.getResolutionFromScale = function (scale, units) {
    var resolution;
    if (scale) {
        if (units == null) {
            units = "degrees";
        }
        var normScale = OpenLayers.Util.normalizeScale(scale);
        resolution = 1 / (normScale * OpenLayers.INCHES_PER_UNIT[units]
                                        * OpenLayers.DOTS_PER_INCH);
    }
    return resolution;
};
```

- With units="degrees" (which EPSG:4490 is, from what I gather) we get inches_per unit = 4374754 (OpenLayers.INCHES_PER_UNIT["degrees"])
- a scale of 1:50000 (which corresponds to 1/50000 = 0.00002) (this is what penLayers.Util.normalizeScale computes) gives normScale = 0.00002
- OpenLayers.DOTS_PER_INCH = 72

We can then calculate resolution as

```
1 / (0.00002 * 4374754 * 72) = 0.00015873908440210453
```

Knowing the center point (lon=100, lat=30), the pixel size of the viewport(w=400, h=600) and the resolution we can then use the calculateBounds function from OpenLayers.Map (see [source](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/lib/OpenLayers/Map.js)):

```
calculateBounds: function(center, resolution) {

        var extent = null;

        if (center == null) {
            center = this.getCachedCenter();
        }
        if (resolution == null) {
            resolution = this.getResolution();
        }

        if ((center != null) && (resolution != null)) {
            var halfWDeg = (this.size.w * resolution) / 2;
            var halfHDeg = (this.size.h * resolution) / 2;

            extent = new OpenLayers.Bounds(center.lon - halfWDeg,
                                           center.lat - halfHDeg,
                                           center.lon + halfWDeg,
                                           center.lat + halfHDeg);
        }

        return extent;
    },
```

which we can reduce to:

```
function calculateBounds(center, resolution, size) {       
    var halfWDeg = (size.w * resolution) / 2;
    var halfHDeg = (size.h * resolution) / 2;
    return {
        "left": center.lon - halfWDeg,
        "bottom": center.lat - halfHDeg,
        "right": center.lon + halfWDeg,
        "top": center.lat + halfHDeg
    };
}
```

Calling this with our values gives:

```
calculateBounds({"lon": 100, "lat": 30}, 0.00015873908440210453, {"w": 400, "h":600});
{ 
    left: 99.96825218311957, 
    bottom: 29.95237827467937,
    right: 100.03174781688043,
    top: 30.04762172532063
}
```

We can then combine all this to a function that works for degrees with scale denominator given:

```
function calculateBounds(center, scaleDenominator, size) {       
    var resolution = 1 / ((1 / scaleDenominator) * 4374754 * 72)
    var halfWDeg = (size.w * resolution) / 2;
    var halfHDeg = (size.h * resolution) / 2;
    return {
        "left": center.lon - halfWDeg,
        "bottom": center.lat - halfHDeg,
        "right": center.lon + halfWDeg,
        "top": center.lat + halfHDeg
    };
}
```

Comment: Wonderful answer. In fact, it seems that the key point here is the `dpi` value. Isn't it?

Comment: Oh, how about the projection? It seems that the above codes is used for caculate the degree directly.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. As long as your users doesn't expect to use the map in the same fashion as a paper map (i.e measuring on it) any value can be used (and I think most mapping libraries use 72 or 96)

Comment: the only thing you need to know about the projection is its units, OpenLayers uses the OpenLayers.INCHES_PER_UNIT[units] array in Utils.js. web mercator uses meters as unit, which means 39.37 instead of 4374754 to calculate resolution

Comment: @atlerfren: Hi, it seems that you are an experter of openlayers, I meet some problems related to it. Can you spare some time to have a checek to this post? http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/61256/12681

Comment: @atlefren How do you account for mercator projection if you want to display this bounding box on google maps?