# How to get bounds coords by center LatLng point, width and height in pixels and zoom?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, scale, resolution, zoom

I have to calculate bounds coordinates to query mongodb box on server side to get data before google maps is loaded.

How can I get four LatLng corners by center LatLng point, window width and height in pixels and given zoom level?

**EDIT:**
This [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/60777/39800) might be helpful but I don't know how to calculate for google maps resolution or scale denominator.